# Postgres process shows 100% CPU but actual usage is 6%, resulting in slow query response

Tags: postgresql, grafana, cloudflare

We are using Postgres as data source for Grafana dashboard. While running the query, the `top` command shows that postgres is using 100% CPU but actual CPU is somewhat 6%, this results in slow query response and thereby Grafana shows 524 timeout error (Cloudflare) (Refer Below Screenshots)

[image]

System COnfiguration:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
RAM: 16GB
CPU: 16 Core Hyper-V

Below is the configuration file

postgressql.conf

```
max_connections = 300   
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' 
ssl = true  
shared_buffers = 4GB
work_mem = 13981kB      
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB      
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix  
effective_io_concurrency = 200  
max_worker_processes = 16
wal_buffers = 16MB
max_wal_size = 8GB
min_wal_size = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9  
random_page_cost = 1.1          
effective_cache_size = 12GB
log_line_prefix = '%t [%p-%l] %q%u@%d '     
log_timezone = 'localtime'
stats_temp_directory = '/var/run/postgresql/9.5-main.pg_stat_tmp'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'localtime'
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'         
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'         
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'  
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8' 
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

I am newbie in postgre, please let me know if I have missed something or if you have any suggesstions.

**Update**
My /boot folder is 100% full, not sure if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The summary line in the `top` output you show has the *cumulative* CPU usage.

One of your cores is busy with a PostgreSQL query, but that is only one of the several cores in the machine, so that is included in the 6.6% "user" CPU shown in the summary line.

The alarming part about that output are the 74.3% "system" CPU time. Three quarters of the cores in your machine are doing operating system maintenance work. There is something seriously wrong. Perhaps you didn't disable transparent huge pages? But to come to a conclusion here, you need deeper analysis by someone who understands Linux.

Comment: I would like to ask even if there is 18% idle cpu, why postgres process shows nearly 100% CPU, why isn't it using the remaining.

Comment: @ShubhRocksGoel I'd suggest reading the documentation of top as it would appear you are misinterpreting what the numbers mean. focusing on that 18% is almost certainly the wrong place to start looking

Comment: It uses 95% of a single CPU core, which is less than 6.6% of the total CPU power available. A single thread can only run on a single core at the same time.